The best way to combine unbiased correlated/independent estimators with unknown variances.
I have a set of unbiased estimators of some physical quantity, denote them as $ (\theta_1 , \theta_2, \ldots , \theta_k)$.
I know that they are correlated but I don't have any information on how they are correlated. Moreover, I don't even know the variances of these estimators but I want to combine them in order to get a better estimator (in terms of variance).
What appears to be the best way and why? Right now I think of average or median for the whole set of estimators but may be it's not the best way.

@JimB should I simply mention in the question that the same one is asked on the other forum or it's more preferable to delete one of the qustions?

It's up to you.  I would first post on the most appropriate forum and at least wait a while to see what sort of responses you get.  But in any event noting that you've simultaneously posted is essential.  The benefit is that someone checking out the other post might see a comment on the other forum that results in an answer for you.  (And if you accept an answer on one of the forums, I would certainly note that in the other forum.)

Let us suppose that each unbiased estimator $\theta_i$ has a variance $\sigma_i^2 $ and the correlation matrix is denoted as $\Gamma = (\Gamma_{i,j})_{1\le i,j \le n}$ with $$\Gamma_{ij} = \cases{1 & if  $i=j$\\ \in[-1,1] & if $i \ne j$}$$
If we choose a random estimator among them, we won't know whether this estimator may be the one with largest variance. However, there is a way to avoid this worst scenario.
Let us define a new unbiased estimator
$$\Theta = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i$$
The variance of this estimator will be
$$\mathbb{V}(\Theta)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j \le n}\sigma_i\sigma_j \Gamma_{ij}\le \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j \le n}\sigma_i\sigma_j=\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i}{n}\right)^2 \le \max_{1\le i\le n} \sigma_i^2$$
Therefore, given the lack of information about the correlation and the variance of these estimators $(\theta_i)_{i}$, with the new estimator $\Theta$, we reduce the uncertainty of picking the worst estimator (the one with largest varaince).

I wonder if it's possible to say something a little stronger: among linear estimators, the unweighted average is minimax by symmetry?

Thank you for your answer. But the question was more about finding the best way to combine. Taking average is one of the ways but is it possible to prove that there is nothing better than this? And I'm talking not only about linear combinations, median also looks like the way to go

@reogeo The problem is that you have no clear criteria (or metrics) to compare two (or many) possible estimator besides the fact that criteria should be based on variance. Hence, the problem is ill-posed. Secondly, there are plethora of possible estimators. Linear combination is just a possibility, but it is possible to have, for example, $e^{\theta_1} + \sqrt{\theta_2}+...$. You should then have a clear domain of estimators. Finally, based on the criteria that I fixed (avoiding worst estimator), median is worse than mean because the median estimator may be the one with largest variance.

@Cat I agreed. The mean seems to be the minimax estimator where the worst scenario is defined as the estimator with largest variance is chosen.
